# Cannot get the data in another page in CI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I have form and when i submit that data are passed to next page i can see that in url. but i when i get and print that it shows nothing , here i have attached my coding

```
<form action="addfilters/add"><input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $filters->id ?> > <input type="submit" value="Add New"></form>
```

my controller

```
<?php
class AddFilters extends Admin_Controller
{
function add(){
echo $this->input->post('id');
}
}
```

URL

```
http://localhost/code/index.php/admin/addfilters/add?id=1
```

but when i print ,it shows nothing , please help me

Comment: Please solve my problem thanks in advence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just used

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/addfilters/add'); ?>
```

top of the form. it works fine :-)